# PowerBuilder - Repeating value suppression list not working on some datawindow columns

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I've tried to suppress some columns in the datawindow. I've already dragged those columns in the suppresion list as shown below.

[image]

But unfortunately when I run the datawindow report, there are values specifically under the column of total carton and total pallet that was not suppressed in the result set. The highlighted values below are supposed to be suppressed as expected because it's a repeated values.

What might be the reason why the mentioned columns above was not able to suppress the repeating values?
Any idea/s or input/s on how can I resolve? 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Based on your example both Sales Order No and Delivery No are also not suppressed.

Comment: Is it a group report and are any of the columns in header, group, footer, or summary sections? I'm not sure PB suppresses repeats when not in the detail band seems we bumped up against this once. Also your sort needs to be same as suppress order- but sure you checked that. As work around you can use [-1] in expressions to manually suppress by referring to previous row and of course handling the case when it's the first row but ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand that your data is hierarchical.

When I present a hierarchy, I use the group presentation style.
I group related information together in the group band and then it will display once per group. In your example, I might create more than one group; Group Pack Key, Group Pack HU, Group Delivery No. It appears to me that Total Carton and Total Pallet would appear in the Group Pack Key band. Play around with it.

Can two sales orders be mixed in the same carton/pallet? You may need guidance as to how the user wants to see the logistics information mixed with the order information.

Sort your data to conform to your group hierarchy otherwise you may get unexpected results.

In datawindow painter, click menu Rows~Create Group...

Here is an example:

[image]

Find more information on using group presentation style here: 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00844.1252/html/pbug/BFCCGFFF.htm

Comment: Appreciate your inputs.